# TikiWiki print to PDF (via wkhtmltopdf) renders login screen

Tags: pdf, tiki-wiki

I'm logged in to my TikiWiki as admin, and I've just set up wkhtmltopdf to enable me to to render the current page to PDF under Admin:General:General Settings:Print/PDF from URL:WebKit(wkhtmltopdf) with the correct path to the binary set.

I am on the page I want to render, and I click on the PDF icon on the page.  After a few seconds, a PDF file downloads.  However, when I open the PDF file, all I see is a page rendered that says:

```
Please log in
Permission denied

Log in
======
Username:
Password:


...etc.
```

Obviously I am already very logged in, and just assumed that this would work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You assume when you are logged in as admin that your perms are transfered to an external program. But that is not the case. wkhtmltopdf does not have the perms when performing the task - it has perms of Anonymous (logged out) user when accessing the content. Either you must set permissions to allow anonymous to view the page or you need to use Tiki Tokens: http://doc.tiki.org/Token+Access

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I had kind of assumed the model was that the php code rendered the page given the current user permissions as usual, but instead of printing them to stdout (which would make its way back to the browser) it instead output the HTML to the stdin of wkhtmltopdf.